Example audio clips of velarization ˠ
I am exploring Irish words on Wiktionary, and found ceol, which says /coːl̪ˠ/ (and has an audio clip). I don't hear the [ˠ] as part of the /l/. Are there any databases which contain clear audio clips showing the various velarized consonants in Irish (f, v, r, n, m, b, p, t, etc.)?

The reason you’re not hearing the velarisation in the Wiktionary sound clip is that it’s not there. In many southern parts of Ireland, the phonetic distinction between broad and slender consonants is eroding (the only completely stable pair that never merges is /sʲ/ and /sˠ/, since /sʲ/ is usually realised as [ʃ]); add to that that the speaker in the clip is quite likely to be a non-native speaker, and you have fertile grounds for loss of distinctive velarisation. To my ear, the velarisation has been completely lost in the Wiktionary recording.
There is a very useful dictionary site called Teanglann, which contains not only the two largest and most standard bilingual dictionaries between English and Irish (Niall Ó Dónaill’s Foclóir Gaeilge–Béarla from 1977, and Thomas de Bhaldraithe’s English–Irish Dictionary from 1959) and the most standard monolingual Irish dictionary (Niall Ó Dónaill and Pádraig Ua Maoileoin’s An Foclóir Beag from 1991), but also a very useful pronunciation database (not quite a database in strict terms, but extremely useful nonetheless).
It contains far from all lookup words in the dictionaries, but there are still many words that have associated pronunciations. Where possible, three pronunciations are given: Ulster (northern), Connacht (central) and Munster (southern). That is the case for the pronunciations of ceol, for instance.
If you listen to all three, you will hear the velarisation most clearly in the Ulster sample, still quite distinctly in the Connacht sample, and only vaguely in the Munster sample, which fits the general tendencies of those dialects.
